# Name of this bond-line formula?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, identification

I don’t know much about chemistry but I recently found the below bond-line structural formula painted on a wall near my place. I really can’t let go of trying to find the name of the compound. If anyone would be so inclined as to relieve me of my suffering, I sure would be grateful!

Thank you and greetings from Sweden!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The full name of the compound is 3,4-methyl​enedioxy​methamphetamine, which is typically abbreviated as "MDMA". It is commonly used recreationally, and is casually referred to as "ecstasy", "molly", "E" and many other names.